# Jinja install for python

Tags: python, installation, jinja2

I don't use Python regularly, but now I have to. I should run a python sctipt that need Jinja. Python2.7 is installed on my Windows XP and works, but I can't find how to install inja package.

Would anybody be so kind to write me a step by step install guide for it?

I have to run this only once to create some outputs for me, so I don't want tp ddep dive into it, so pls. forgive me if it is a very beginner level question.

Thx

Comment: Questions about installing software (even development software) belong on superuser.

Comment: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/#installation

Comment: I think thats debatable @SingleNegationElimination, installing libraries is part of the development process, and with some languages getting the libraries installed correctly is half the battle (Particularly with C/C++, god knows that language has its share of headaches with library setup)

Comment: if the solutions above not working try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72120645

Answer (score 16, accepted):

have a look at [this](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/). You can use [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall) or [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install jinja. Just enter those command into a DOS prompt

```
easy_install Jinja2
```

or

```
pip install Jinja2
```

You should have easy_install.exe  [bundled with your python on windows](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#windows-notes)

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the error I am receiving: `error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2': Permission denied

`

Comment: Probably you have to install them as a super user try prefix those command with "sudo"

Comment: You'll need to install it as root (ie sudo pip install Jinja2)  if your using system python. I *strongly* recomend however adopting one of the virtualenv variants. Trust me, you'll never look back, plus you dont need to endanger the system python install by operating in root user space.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to install jinja2 as a dependency for Ansible and didn't want to use **pip** or **pip3**. Installing **python-jinja2** package did the trick:

```
apt install python-jinja2
```

Comment: This did the trick. Tried adding PYTHONPATH to PATH, installing jinja2 as sudo via pip, checking if jinja2 is installed within the path-directives given in PYTHONPATH before - no success. Skipping installing jinja2 via pip and installing it via os-package installer made it accessable.
I am using Redhat/CentOS, so i'm not using apt but microdnf:
`microdnf install --nodocs python27-python-jinja2`

Comment: Works, but does not install the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

For updates *(git path)* see: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/intro/

```
git clone git://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2.git
cd jinja2
sudo
cp -r jinja2 /usr/lib/python2.X/site-packages
exit
```

Note: The jinja2 *subdirectory* in jinja2 already includeds all the files packaged as a python library and is ready for your /usr/lib...