# Trouble installing Jinja2 on Windows

Tags: python, installation, jinja2, python-3.3

I'm running Python3.3 on Win64 and am having trouble following the installation instructions for Jinja2. I followed the suggestion here ([Jinja install for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726983/jinja-install-for-python)) but my installation of Python 3.3 doesn't have a easy_install.exe as described. I downloaded the dstribute-0.6.45.tar file and ran the distribute_setup.py as described in the README file, but when I type easy_install Jinja2 from the python shell, I get a SyntaxError.

I've been spoiled by years of double clicking on setup.exe files to install software and am unfamiliar with terms such as "egg" and "pip" when reading reading through the Jinja2 installation instruction. If someone could shed some light it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use easy install and pip: use windows setuptools : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
Python for windows extensions is also very helpfull :

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had followed the link you provided before and ran the ez_setup.py script provided but get the error: ez_setup.py line 106 "except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:" SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Comment: You cannot use the normal 2.x installer for Python 3.3  http://www.khattam.info/howto-install-easy_install-and-pip-in-python-3-windows-2011-09-27.html

Comment: Ah. That worked. Many thanks. I had followed the steps you provided *except* for the "Run as Administrator" part. Wish I had a nickel for every time I missed that step.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools

1. Download and install appropriate setuptool.exe for your Computer.
2. Download and install appropriate jinja2.exe for your Computer.
3. From your command prompt install C:\Python27\Lib\Jinja2(version)>setup.py install
4. A jinja2 folder should be created in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\jinja2
5. In your .yaml file add:

```
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Now your application must run.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Python >=2.7.9 or Python >=3.4 `pip` is included. You may need to add the $PYTHONPATH\Scripts or %PYTHONPATH%\Scripts folder to your PATH variable in order to access `pip` directly, but you will know if pip is there if you can do `python -m pip --version`.