# when i use docker-compose to install a fastapi project, i got AssertionError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, fastapi

when I use docker-compose to install a fastapi project, I got `AssertionError: jinja2 must be installed to use Jinja2Templates`

but when I use env to install it, that will be run well.

my OS:

Ubuntu18.04STL

my requirements.txt:

```
fastapi~=0.68.2
starlette==0.14.2
pydantic~=1.8.1

uvicorn~=0.12.3
SQLAlchemy~=1.4.23

# WSGI
Werkzeug==1.0.1

pyjwt~=1.7.0

# async-exit-stack~=1.0.1
# async-generator~=1.10

jinja2~=2.11.2

# assert aiofiles is not None, "'aiofiles' must be installed to use FileResponse"
aiofiles~=0.6.0
python-multipart~=0.0.5

requests~=2.25.0
pyyaml~=5.3.1
# html-builder==0.0.6
loguru~=0.5.3
apscheduler==3.7.0

pytest~=6.1.2
html2text==2020.1.16
mkdocs==1.2.1
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /server
COPY requirements.txt /server/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /server/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  figbox_api:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command:  uvicorn app.main:app --port 8773 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    volumes:
    - .:/server
    ports:
    - 8773:8773
```

Do I need to provide some other information?

Thanks

Comment: That seems like it should work.  If you `docker-compose run figbox_api pip list`, is `jinja2` listed in the installed packages?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. when I did pip list jinja2 was listed as `Jinja2     2.11.2`

Comment: should I install another jinja2 version?

Comment: I had the same problem and resolved when install both latest jinja2 and fastapi. (Not enough to install only latest jinja2.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a same problem on heroku, the error comes from Jinja2
version 2.11.x and it run locally but not in Heroku.

Just install latest version of jinja2 it will work fine in your case too.

```
pip install Jinja2==3.1.2
or 
pip install Jinja2 --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Have had same issue, using Jinja2 (without version annotation) solved it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35120869)